# Get the local file system path to the downloaded dependencies and plugins in build.gradle.kts

Tags: build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have added the grpc protobuf kotlin dependencies and plugins into my `build.gradle.kts`
like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${project.ext["grpcKotlinVersion"]}")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${project.ext["grpcVersion"]}")
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${project.ext["protobufVersion"]}"
    }
    plugins {
        create("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${project.ext["grpcVersion"]}"
        }
        create("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${project.ext["grpcKotlinVersion"]}:jdk8@jar"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, somewhere else in the file, I need to perform certain operations and need the local files system paths of these files.

```
exec {
    // some operations
}
```

Is there a way I can get it file path. I checked the layout object but cannot figure the location. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Step 1. Create a configuration

To access the downloaded files of a dependency you need to resolve the respective configuration. In your case it would be the `implementation` configuration. But a much better idea would be creating a new one instead:

```kotlin
val myDownloadConfiguration by configurations.creating {
    // This ensures you can access artifacts
    isCanBeResolved = true 
    // Setting isTransitive to false makes it easier to access the files of a dependency.
    isTransitive = false  
}
```

## Step 2. Add dependencies

Keep your existing `implementation` dependencies. They are still needed as before, nothing changes in that regard.

Add dependencies whose files you want to access to the newly created configuration. It's perfectly fine to add the same dependencies to both `implementation` and `myDownloadConfiguration` at the same time.

```kotlin
dependencies {
    myDownloadConfiguration("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${project.ext["grpcKotlinVersion"]}")
    myDownloadConfiguration("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${project.ext["grpcVersion"]}")
}
```

## Step 3. Resolve the configuration

*I'd like to mention that resolving configurations during configuration phase is not recommended. Do processing of any kind in the form of a task.*

```kotlin
val processMyDependencies by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        val dependencyFiles: Set<File> = myDownloadCongifuration.files {
            it.group == "io.grpc" && it.name == "grpc-kotlin-stub"
        }

        // Repeat the same for other dependencies
    }
}
```

Note that if the configuration's `isTransitive` was `true` then `myDownloadCongifuration.files` would return all files of all transitive dependencies along with the dependency's own files. Filtering them out would require going through `myDownloadCongifuration.resolvedConfiguration`, which is slightly more verbose:

```kotlin
val processMyDependencies by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        val resolvedDependencies = myDownloadCongifuration.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
        val dependency = resolvedDependencies.single {
            it.moduleGroup == "io.grpc" && it.moduleName == "grpc-kotlin-stub"
        }
        val dependencyFiles: List<File> = dependency.moduleArtifacts.map { it.file }

        // Repeat the same for other dependencies
    }
}
```

## Reasoning Behind the Approach

One reason to create your own configuration is because all configurations have their own intended purpose, as designed by the configuration author. `implementation` wasn't designed to be resolved by users and then its files being messed with.

Aside from that, there might be problems with ambiguous configuration attributes, extra dependencies implicitly added via plugins, or via configurations this one extends from, and so on. By creating your own configuration you avoid any potential problems of that kind.

Secondly, you wouldn't be able to resolve the `implementation` configuration in the first place, and would get an error instead as it is not resolvable (and no, settings its `isCanBeResolved` to `true` is not a good idea).